# List Name of Controls and Form

Tags: winforms, controls

I am using visual studio 2003 and Windows platform  and i want some tool which give me the list of controls name and control type like button,textbox etc.. in the form
is there any way to do this by tool or by any code ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is ***toolbox*** in Visual Studio IDE which will give you the details.

Comment: I think OP wants to list the name of controls programatically.

Comment: i can not find it where exactly is toolbox ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Controls` collection for the Form. You can get the array of controls present in the form from that. In order to get the type, you will need to loop through the collection and get `GetType().FullName` property for each element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programatically with something like the following.  This code will step through each container on a form and display details for each control using recursion.  It indents the text according to how many levels deep the control is buried inside containers (like panels etc).

```
    private void PrintControls()
    {
        // Print form coords
        Debug.Print("\n" + this.Name + ": "
            + "\n\tLocation=" + this.Location.ToString()
            + "\n\tSize=" + this.Size.ToString()
            + "\n\tBottom=" + this.Bottom.ToString() 
            + " Right=" + this.Right.ToString()
            + "\n\tMinimumSize=" + this.MinimumSize.ToString() 
            + " MaximumSize=" + this.MaximumSize.ToString());

        // Print coords for controls and containers
        foreach (Control C in this.Controls)
        {
            RecurseThroughControls(C, 1);
        }
    }

    private void RecurseThroughControls(Control C, int Tabs)
    {
        string Indent = "";
        for (int t = 0; t < Tabs; t++)
        {
            Indent += "\t";
        }

        Debug.Print(Indent + "Name=" + C.Name + " Type=" + C.ToString()
            + "\n" + Indent + "\tLocation=" + C.Location.ToString()
            + "\n" + Indent + "\tSize=" + C.Size.ToString()
            + "\n" + Indent + "\tBottom=" + C.Bottom.ToString() 
            + " Right=" + C.Right.ToString());
        if (C.HasChildren)
        {
            foreach (Control Child in C.Controls)
            {
                RecurseThroughControls(Child, Tabs + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```